# Is it possible to host a FOG Project server on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, pxe-boot, disk-image, imaging, ghost

I am totally new to imaging in general and have been looking into different options. The [FOG Project](https://www.fogproject.org/) seems especially appealing because of cost. My company makes pretty extensive use of Amazon Web Services, including hosting all of our server-side stuff in EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to install FOG Project on an EC2 instance and use that to deploy images to local Windows machines. I know this requires setting the Windows machines to boot via PXE, and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813604/booting-via-ipxe-in-ec2) leads me to believe that, because of what is essentially a "firewall" problem, it might not be possible. But, as I said, I am totally new to all of this and could be misreading that.

Does anyone here have any experience with setting up a FOG Project server in the cloud? Is that even possible, or does it need to be on a server connected to the LAN? Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: PXE won't work inside of EC2 because it required DHCP functionality not currently supported in AWS. I haven't ever tested with FOG but gPXE could boot a LAN machine using an image stored on a EC2 HTTP server. It may be possible with FOG. Why not test it out?